# False-positive: Fix this implementation of IDisposable to conform to the dispose pattern

Tags: c#, sonarqube

My class implements `IDisposable` and follows the pattern where

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

But Sonar is still telling me I need to implement the dispose pattern...

[Sonar Rule 3881 (IDisposable should be implemented correctly)](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-3881)

Is this a defect with sonar or have I missed something?

Comment: Perhaps it detects that you do not implement a finalizer in your class, so the `SuppressFinalize` call has no effect?

Comment: Plus, your `Dispose(bool)` should be protected? This is at least what SonarQube explicitly says:
`protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)`

Comment: 1) then it really should say so but the pattern I have used is identical to the one I have implmented, 
2) good eyes, I'll try that but not sure it cares

Comment: 1) It actually does :)
`TrackedMethodStrategyManager.Dispose() should contain only a 
call to TrackedMethodStrategyManager.Dispose(true) and if the 
class contains a finalizer, call to GC.SuppressFinalize(this).`

Comment: @MarekFekete - I tried the `protected`, as suspected it didn't care. I'll try the first suggestion next and see if that knocks it on the head.

Comment: @MarekFekete - the `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` was it - please create this as your answer and I'll accept it - thanks - looks like the guidance on sonar is incorrect.

Comment: I posted the answer, but I suggest you accept the answer of @Valeri - SonarSource Team, it's far more complete. Glad to be of help though.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I saw that you already fixed the issue, but in case someone else has the same problem, I will elaborate on the rule requirements.

The idea of this rule is to allow potential derived classes to correctly dispose the members of your class. Hence if your class is sealed, the rule assumes your class correctly disposes itself and does nothing (there is another rule, [S2931](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-2931) which checks if your class contains `IDisposable` fields that need to be disposed).

If the class is not sealed, the rule checks if it has a base class that implements `IDisposable`. If it has and your class also implements `IDisposable`, the rule will recommend to remove your implementation (e.g. remove the `IDisposable` interface from your class) and override the base class's `protected Dispose(bool)` method.

If the base class does not implement `IDisposable`, the rule requires a `protected virtual Dispose(bool)` method (to allow the inheritors to correctly dispose your class).

If your class contains a finalizer, i.e. destructor, the rule checks if its content is a single invocation of `Dispose(false)`.

The rule checks if the content of the `Dispose()` method (the one from the interface) contains a single invocation of `Dispose(true)`. If your class has a finalizer, the rule requires an additional call to `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`.

Basically these are the correct implementations of `IDisposable` according to the rule:

**Sealed class**

```
public sealed class Foo1 : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Cleanup
    }
}
```

**Simple implementation**

```
public class Foo2 : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Cleanup
    }
}
```

**Implementation with a finalizer**

```
public class Foo3 : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Cleanup
    }

    ~Foo3()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you intend to change the compliant samples in sonarqube to match the above?

Comment: Yes, we will change the description.

Comment: For me I was still getting the warning even though I am implementing the "Simple implementation", i.e. like Foo2. I changed to the "sealed class" implementation shown here to make the warning go away

Comment: `GC.SuppressFinalize()` **must always** be there if the class is not sealed, no matter if the class itself has a finalizer or not. If one of the derived classes decides to implement a finalizer, there is no decent way to add it in a derived class. Please see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern#basic-dispose-pattern

Answer (score 2):

Do not call `GC.SuppressFinalize()` in your `Dispose()` method, unless your class implements a finalizer.

Comment: `GC.SuppressFinalize()` **must always** be there if the class is not sealed, see my above comment.

Comment: @Marek: can you elaborate on your why?

Comment: @Thariama: only in the way that I was trying to deduce the possible solution from Sonar's message; which, while not worded strictly, suggested that the call was perhaps unwanted by Sonar. As to whether the rule is actually good to adhere to, I'd rather tend to agree with @bitbonk - call `SuppressFinalize` even if you do not have the finalizer implemented - derivees wouldd be one reason, possibility to forget to add it if you add the finalizer later on is another one.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was missing `virtual` keyword:

```
private bool disposed = false;
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposed && disposing)
    {
        _dbContext.Dispose();
    }
    disposed = true;
}
```